# SwiftUI List item delete animation does not play after a confirmation dialog

Tags: swiftui, core-data, swiftui-list

I'm trying to build a List in SwiftUI that sources its data from a CoreData FetchRequest and supports entity deletes after a confirmation dialog. However in my implementation when the row is deleted after a confirmation, the list item delete animation does not play. The animation does play if there is no confirmation dialog. Here is an MRE. I'm using Xcode Version 14.3 (14E222b) and Swift 5. Please help. Thank you

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    @State private var showingDeleteAlert = false
    @State private var toBeDeleted : Item?

    func promptToDeleteItem(item: Item) {
        self.toBeDeleted = item
        self.showingDeleteAlert = true
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                    }
                    .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                        Button("Delete After Confirm", action: {
                            promptToDeleteItem(item:item)
                        })
                        .tint(Color.red)
                        Button("Delete Without Confirm", action: {
                            reallyDeleteItem(item:item)
                        })
                        .tint(Color.red)
                    }
                    .alert(isPresented: self.$showingDeleteAlert) {
                        Alert(title: Text("Delete"),
                              primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
                            reallyDeleteItem(item:toBeDeleted!)
                                self.toBeDeleted = nil
                            }, secondaryButton: .cancel() {
                                self.toBeDeleted = nil
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func reallyDeleteItem(item: Item) {
        withAnimation {
            viewContext.delete(item)
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()

class DataManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    let container: NSPersistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestListDelete")
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, _ in }
    }
}

@main
struct TestListDeleteApp: App {
    @StateObject private var manager: DataManager = DataManager()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, manager.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```